# Return cancelled after outbound has already been taken: what are my rights?

Tags: air-travel, cancellations, passenger-rights

I'm trying to help out a stranded traveler in this thread. [British Airways (one-leg) flight cancelled due to Covid](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/161886/british-airways-one-leg-flight-cancelled-due-to-covid)

They flew to Delhi with BA but the return was cancelled due to Covid. I'm trying to find out what specific rules apply here. I wasn't able to find anything that covers the specific case where the cancellation happens AFTER the itinerary has already been started. Everything I  found on "cancellation" seems to assume that the cancellation happens BEFORE the outbound flight which either results in a rebooking or a full refund.

I would assume that the airline is required to bring you back, but that can be expensive for them if they have to rebook you  on a different (non code-share) airline, so they will drag their feet. For a partially flown itinerary, refund is very difficult since it requires pricing out the individual legs.

Specific questions:

1. What are the passenger rights ? If location is relevant, lets assume governed under EU law. What specific laws apply?
2. Is there a time limit on how much later (then the original return) the airline can rebook you, regardless of how expensive for them it is? In this example it seems to be 4 or 5 days later.
3. Can the customer instead ask for a partial refund and how would that have to be calculated?

Any other tips & tricks would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that [this page](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/passenger-rights/air/index_en.htm) says that "The outbound and return flights are always considered as two separate flights even if they were booked as part of one reservation."  So I suspect that such a person is due either a refund for the unused portion of their ticket or a re-booking to the final destination of the return leg.

Comment: Not sure about what rights the passenger has, but BA will refund the cost of the return leg to the passenger. I had a phone call with them in November asking them about solutions should this exact thing happen and they recommended I fly the onward leg and then take the refund of the return leg (given there are no rebooking options provided by BA) and just book a flight by a carrier allowed under the air bubble agreement with the destination country.